# What is the use of default_backend() in "from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend"?

Tags: python, cryptography

Example code (Copied):

```
>>> from cryptography import x509
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
>>> cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
>>> cert.serial_number
2
```

Comment: @President James K. Polk
Broken link above https://web.archive.org/web/20201126212753/https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/

Comment: Thanks @AndyGee, I've added a new corrected comment. You can't edit comments after 5 minutes let alone 18 months.

Comment: As you can [read here](https://cryptography.io/en/35.0.0/hazmat/backends/), the backend arguments are no longer required.